# Find the probability of using debit card

Tags: probability

Our professor gave this question as assignment, My question is does this question have all information needed to solve it? I asked her and she said it has all information but still I cannot figure out how I can solve it with just knowing the probability of using debit card in supermarket. Can someone please provide me a tip on how I can solve this question with this information or is it solvable?

> According to a recent Interact survey, 28% of consumers use their
>   debit cards in supermarkets. Find the probability that they use debit
>   cards in only other stores or not at all.

Comment: This is hard to understand.  Maybe you just mean that $72\%$ do not use their debit cards in supermarkets.  Is that possible?

Comment: Draw a Venn diagram. One circle for "consumers who use debit cards in supermarkets". Another circle for "consumers who use debit cards only in non-supermarket stores, or not at all". Which areas of the diagram can possibly contain any people?

Comment: The question is clearly flawed, but since it's so _badly_ flawed, it's very likely that you didn't write it down correctly. Was it a printed question, or did you copy it from a question written on the board?

Comment: @quasi Its a printed question and that's all information provided

Comment: @HenningMakholm I just know the probability of customers using their debit cards in super market and no other information. How can I draw Vein diagram for customers using their debit cards in non-supermarket stores?

Comment: Then it's the teacher's fault. To make sure, can you post an image of the actual assignment sheet?

Comment: If the problem you posted is exactly what was assigned, don't bother with it. Wait until the teacher shows a "solution", and get back to us.

Comment: What course is it for?

Comment: @quasi probability and statistics course

Comment: @quasi Does it mean finding probability of not using in supermarket $(1-P(s))$?

Comment: The problem is just gibberish. Pure and simple. I am slightly appalled that problem was designed by a professor.

Answer (score 1):

The intended answer is mostly likely $72\%$.  This is because to say that a consumer uses his/her debit cards "in only other stores or not at all" is logically equivalent to saying that he/she does *not* use his/her debit cards in supermarkets.  So if $28\%$ of consumers do use their debit cards in supermarkets, then $72\%$ do not.

That said, the problem strikes me as not well worded.  In giving the answer of $72\%$, I am assuming that what's meant by "the probability that they use debit cards..." is the probability that a randomly selected *individual* consumer uses his/her debit cards only in other stores or not at all.  As stated, however, it's asking about the probability that an entire collection of consumers use their debit cards in a certain way.  Whether you read the "they" as referring to the entire set of consumers, or just to the $28\%$ who use them at supermarkets (as quasi's answer does), the answer is $0$.  It's possible the person writing the question really meant it this way, as quasi suggests; I think it's more likely they were just a bit sloppy in their wording.  I know I sometimes am.

Comment: That makes more sense than my interpretation. With your interpretation, there is at least some math value, not just a grammar-based trick.. I think I'll delete my answer.

Comment: the problem doesn't say that 28% of consumers use their cards in the supermarket... it says that the result of a survey was 28%.

Comment: @SlugPue, I'm afraid I don't understand what you're getting at.  How does the distinction you're making affect the interpretation of the problem?